# Is it possible to return a data.table without j?

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to return a `data.table` without any j columns?

Quite often I just want the unique combinations of a key or set of keys.

```
library(data.table)

## Warpbreaks data
wb <- as.data.table(warpbreaks)

## Say I just want the summary of wool / tension combos
## I would like to do one of these, but neither works
wb[ , j = NULL, keyby = list(wool, tension)]  ## <--- Seems legit
wb[keyby = list(wool, tension)]               ## <--- Even better!

## This works, but is two steps:
subset(wb[ , .N, keyby=list(wool, tension)], select=-N)

## This almost works, but there is no key
unique(wb[ , list(wool, tension)])
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I almost always just use `.N` in this case and then keep it around (since it's fairly harmless). I guess the idiomatic way to drop it would be like `wb[,.N, keyby=.(wool,tension)][, !"N", with=FALSE]` rather than `subset`. The relevant FR is over here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1269

Comment: Related to [#1245](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1245)

Comment: For now, `unique(wb[ , .(wool, tension)])[order(wool, tension)]`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Or `setkey(unique(wb[ , .(wool, tension)]))` instead of retyping the names.

Comment: @Frank faster for yours is `wb[ , TRUE, keyby = .(wool, tension)][ , !"V1", with = FALSE]`

Comment: @MichaelChirico even faster will be dropping V1 by reference

Comment: Great suggestions from the `data.table` jedis!